# Do I add an acknowledgement upon initial submission? (to an anonymous review)

Tags: acknowledgement

When do I add anacknowledgement to a (philosophy of science) article?. Even though the acknowledgement does not specify my name, it does say something about where the work was done. Do I add the acknowledgement only when the article is accepted?

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I only add acknowledgements after the paper no longer requires blinding. Acknowledgements add nothing for a review, and "Thanks to [blinded], supported by grant [blinded] from [blinded]" always seemed too silly to bother with.